# Python Selenium BeautifulSoup Page Source Does Not Display Everything

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

**Goal:** 
Hello I am pretty new to Web and Selenium. I am currently trying to grab a value from my JIRA Board. Here:

[image: enter image description here,]

**Problem:** 
For some reason that value does not show up in the page source. I think it might be a JavaScript rendered value? or maybe it gets generated after the page loads. I tried using `implicitly_wait`, `WebDriverWait`, and `switch_Frame` but nothing seems to work. =/

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
#import requests
import json
import base64
import sys
import getopt
import argparse
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from jira import JIRA
from jira.client import GreenHopper
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

JIRA_INSTALLATION = "jira.turn.com"
STATE_IN_PROGRESS = "In Progress"
STATE_RESOLVED    = "Resolved"
STATE_CLOSED      = "Closed"
options = {'server': 'https://jira.turn.com'}
CUR_TIMEZONE_SHIFT = timedelta(hours=7)

def main(argv):
    p=argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Gets a set of completed stories and list them with their implementation time.")
    p.add_argument('filter_id', help="Id of the filter that contains completed stories.")
    p.add_argument('-u', dest='username', help="JIRA username. Needs to have read access to all tickets returned from the search filter.")
    p.add_argument('-p', dest='password', help="Password for the JIRA user to use for API calls.")
    args = p.parse_args(argv)

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://jira.turn.com/')
    driver.find_element_by_id("login-form-username").send_keys(args.username)
    driver.find_element_by_id ("login-form-password").send_keys(args.password)
    driver.find_element_by_id("login").click()
    #driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    #ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get('https://jira.turn.com/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=184&view=reporting&chart=controlChart&days=30&column=1214&column=1298')

    #WebDriverWait
    soup_level1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')#'html.parser')#'lxml')
    print soup_level1.find(id='ghx-chart-snapshot')#find(id='content').find(id="gh").find(id="ghx-content-main").find(id="ghx-chart-header"))
    print soup_level1.find(id='ghx-chart-snapshot').find(id='ghx-chart-snapshot')

    driver.quit()

    return 

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**Output:**

```
<div id="ghx-chart-snapshot"></div>
None
```

Comment: After some investigation on the page source, it looks like a JavaScript is ran to generate "ghx-chart-snapshot" of <dd and <dt.

**Output:** GH.tpl.reports.controlChart.renderChartSnapshots = function(opt_data, opt_ignored) {
  return '<div class="ghx-chart-snapshot">..........'</dd></dl><dl><dt class="js-chart-snapshot-issue-count">' + soy.$$escapeHtml(opt_data.issueCount) + '</dt><dd>' + soy.$$escapeHtml("Issues") + '</dd></dl></div>';
};

Comment: Is it possible for me to use the Selenium **driver.execute_script()** command on this JavaScript?